# Create user defined function in SQL Server for dates not older than 14

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Not sure how to create this UDF. I have read through the existing questions but just not sure of the syntax.

I want to save this query as a view but can't as I have declarations already

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME

SELECT @ENDDATE = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)+' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
SELECT @STARTDATE = DATEADD(D, -1, @ENDDATE)--'-7'
SELECT @ENDDATE = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)+' 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)

SELECT
    LTRIM(CIJ.ORDERACCOUNT) 'ACCOUNT'
    ,LTRIM(CIJ.SALESID) 'TOMKIN ORDER #'
    ,LTRIM(CIJ.INVOICEID) 'TOMKIN INVOICE #'
    ,CIJ.PURCHASEORDER 'YOUR ORDER #'
FROM 
    CUSTINVOICEJOUR CIJ
WHERE 
    CIJ.INVOICEDATE >= @STARTDATE AND CIJ.INVOICEDATE <= @ENDDATE
ORDER BY 
    CIJ.INVOICEDATE,CIJ.INVOICEID
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated

Comment: Do you want a udf or a view?

Comment: I want to end up with a view.

Comment: it should say SELECT @STARTDATE = DATEADD(D, -14, @ENDDATE)--'-7'

Comment: There are far easier ways of getting a `datetime` value that's set to midnight on the day 14 days before today than what you've shown. And is there any reason you're ignoring anything that happens during the last second of the day? (For `datetime` comparisons, it's usually better to use `>= @Start` and `< @End` and have both values be midnights)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query converted into a view. Note that you cannot pass parameters into a view and you cannot specify an order.

```
CREATE VIEW Makdaddy ([ACCOUNT], [TOMKIN ORDER #], [TOMKIN INVOICE #], [YOUR ORDER #])
AS
SELECT
     LTRIM(CIJ.ORDERACCOUNT) 'ACCOUNT'
   , LTRIM(CIJ.SALESID) 'TOMKIN ORDER #'
   , LTRIM(CIJ.INVOICEID) 'TOMKIN INVOICE #'
   , CIJ.PURCHASEORDER 'YOUR ORDER #'
FROM CUSTINVOICEJOUR CIJ
WHERE CIJ.INVOICEDATE >= DATEADD(day,-14,GETDATE())
  AND CIJ.INVOICEDATE <= GETDATE()
```

When you call the view, you can order the columns and perform additional filtering.

```
SELECT *
FROM Makdaddt
ORDER BY [ACCOUNT]
```

Here's your query converted into a udf. This is probably a better approach since your start date may change.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Makdaddy (@StartDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
  SELECT
       LTRIM(CIJ.ORDERACCOUNT) 'ACCOUNT'
     , LTRIM(CIJ.SALESID) 'TOMKIN ORDER #'
     ,  LTRIM(CIJ.INVOICEID) 'TOMKIN INVOICE #'
     , CIJ.PURCHASEORDER 'YOUR ORDER #'
  FROM CUSTINVOICEJOUR CIJ
  WHERE CIJ.INVOICEDATE >= @StartDate
    AND CIJ.INVOICEDATE <= GETDATE()
);
```